# Is allObjects() method in Realm was deprecated?

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to display list items in a ListView using Realm offline database. I followed some tutorial and he used allObjects() method that cannot be resolved with me!!

Can you help me in this?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.
            Builder().
            deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded().
            build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);

    Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(config);
    realm.beginTransaction();
    List<Car> cars = realm.**allObjects**(Car.class);
    String[] names = new String[cars.size()];
    for(int i=0; i<names.length;i++){
        names[i]=cars.get(i).getName();
    }

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,names);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> `realm.beginTransaction();`

You don't need that.

> `List<Car> cars = realm.**allObjects**(Car.class);`

`realm.allObjects(Car.class)` was replaced with `realm.where(Car.class).findAll()`. Specifically, `allObjects` was deprecated in 0.90.0, and removed in 0.91.0, see [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0900).

Comment: And instead of `ArrayAdapter`, you should use [RealmBaseAdapter](https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters).

Comment: RealmBaseAdapter automatically adds a RealmChangeListener to your RealmResults (and calls `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`), which means that any write made to the database from any threads(!) will automatically reflect in the RealmResults, and the adapter will be automatically notified of this (and will show the new data set). So you don't need to manually get the new data or update your data by hand, because Realm already does that for you - if you don't map out the fields into a normal List, but keep using RealmResults instead.

Comment: You can read more about that in [the documentation on `Notifications`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#notifications).